# Undefined method 'bool' during migration (Rails Heroku Postgres)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I have a locally-developed app that is working fine on postgres, however, once I uploaded it to heroku, I'm receiving an error in the migration:

```
undefined method `bool' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQL::TableDefinition:0x007fb335472530>/app/db/migrate/20150603202509_devise_create_admins.rb:5:in `block in change'
```

Line 5 of the referenced migration:

```
t.boolean :manage_users, default: false
```

I didn't have any problems locally, just now that it's on heroku. Using `pg v0.18.2`

Comment: Which versions of postgres and the pg gem are you using? Make sure they are compatible with heroku ;)

Comment: Using `pg v0.18.2` which is the same as another working heroku app. And yes, the migration is being ran on the `t.boolean` line above, which I too thought was strange because it mentioned the "bool" method.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this error too.
I did this to cause the error:

```
$ rails generate scaffold MyObject isGreen:bool
```

I fixed it by changing `bool` to `boolean`:

```
$ rails generate scaffold MyObject isGreen:boolean
```